# How to escape stable pattern in conway's game of life?

Tags: algorithm, logic, automata, conways-game-of-life

I built conway's game of life and its working fine but my game after many generations is either ending with no lives or reaching a stable pattern which it can't escape.

For example I have followed these rules

```
Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if by underpopulation. 
         (live_cell = True and neighourhood < 2)
Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation. 
         (live_cell = True and neighourhood == 2 or neighourhood == 3)
Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation. 
         (live_cell = True and neighourhood > 3)
Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction. 
         (live_cell = False and neighourhood == 3)
```

This is my game of life matrix where 1 is life and 0 not

```
000000
001000
010100
001000
000000
000000
```

and this is its corresponding neighbourhood maps created by my programe

```
011100
122210
124210
122210
011100
000000
```

After reaching this pattern even after thousands of generation its still stuck in this pattern itself. I dont know how to escape this pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the space is finite, then the number of possible configurations is finite and then the GoL will end either in a stable pattern or in a loop. If the space is very small (as it looks like) then you will observe only stupid behavior. You need at least to use a much bigger space (500x500), fill it with 1's at many places and look; that is the basic *play* with GoL. The next step is to build interesting configurations, and there exists a lot that have been discovered over time, for examples see [GoL Pattern Library](https://conwaylife.appspot.com/library). Basic well-known patterns are gliders, glider-guns, oscillators... You will discover that GoL is in fact a very interesting way of programming: the initial configuration is a program code executed by the machine that you can see evolving on your screen. But that programming is not so easy, especially if you want to obtain a specific behavior!

Answer (score 0):

To escape stable patterns, I introduced another life form, bugs that sense life cells, eat life cells, excrete gliders and die in an explosion of random life cells. I figured that would keep'm going :)

https://www.ashware.nl/buglife/

https://github.com/Esger/buglife